# ADC minimum value is half of max

Tags: microcontroller, adc, atmel

I'm trying to read an analog value using the ADC of a ATSAM4E microcontroller. The problem i have is that it always reads 2047 or 2046 when the pin is connected to GND and 4096 when connected to VCC. I don't have it configured in differential mode.

Here is the code for it:

```
void adc_init(void){
    struct afec_config afec_cfg;
    afec_enable(AFEC0);
    afec_get_config_defaults(&afec_cfg);
    afec_init(AFEC0, &afec_cfg);
    afec_set_trigger(AFEC0, AFEC_TRIG_SW);
    afec_channel_enable(AFEC0, AFEC_CHANNEL_0);
}

//every 100ms
printf("CHANNEL 0: %d\r\n\n", afec_channel_get_value(AFEC0, AFEC_CHANNEL_0));
afec_start_software_conversion(AFEC0);
```

I don't know what the problem is. The ADC clock is 6MHz, so waiting 100ms between conversions should be sufficient to ensure it is finished.

It is a bit suspicious that the value is always so close to half. Least i got was 1790 but these "smaller" values occur after disconnecting the pin from VCC.

Anyone have any idea what it might be?

Comment: Looks like a differential ADC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read and do this...

> The analog offset of the AFE is configured in the AOFF field in the Channel Offset Compensation register
>   (AFEC_COCR). The offset is only available in Single-ended mode. The field AOFF must be configured to 2048
>   (mid scale of the DAC) when there is no offset error to compensate.To compensate for an offset error of n LSB
>   (positive or negative), the field AOFF must be configured to 2048 + n.

Page 1276 of the [spec sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-11157-32-bit-Cortex-M4-Microcontroller-SAM4E16-SAM4E8_Datasheet.pdf).

Comment: Yep, this was it.I didn't read this in the datasheet thinking that i didn't need to use it, but apparently it starts with an offset of 2048 by default. Writing 0 to the offset fixed it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user3808318 yes, I would not have intuitively thought that either, but then again it makes sense to allow the user to apply a max +- half range offset. Though you would think it would reset to 2048...